# Free scroll in Jetpack Compose

Tags: scroll, android-jetpack-compose

This is a modification of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69360707/how-can-i-scroll-in-both-directions-in-jetpack-compose/73618122#73618122). I have an isometric grid of images and curious - is it possible to scroll it in free ways (diagonals included). Currently I have this code and it's possible to scroll 2D:

```
val scrollStateHorizontal = rememberScrollState()
val scrollStateVertical = rememberScrollState()

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .horizontalScroll(scrollStateHorizontal)
        .verticalScroll(scrollStateVertical)
) {
    for (i in 0..8) {
        for (j in 0..7) {
            val start = (y % 2 * 0.5 + x) * width
            val top = i * height * 0.5
            Image(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = start.dp, top = top.dp), painter = ...)                
        }
    }
}
```

What is interesting:

1. Can I scroll diagonally?
2. How can I optimize it (memory consumption, etc.)? Maybe I should use `LazyHorizontalGrid` including `LazyVerticalGrid`/`LazyColumn`/`LazyRow`?

It seems, `LazyHorizontalGrid` can't be modified simply adding `Modifier.verticalScroll`. And it has a lag for first few seconds of scrolling (maybe for caching items) while simple `Box` scrolling acts smoothly from the start.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there's no official support for this, as far as I know. The only way you could implement this as of the current stable, is by using `LazyLayout` Composable, or by modifying the `verticalScroll` (or horizontal) Modifiers. Read here. It is a recent addition to the APIs so the documentation is very scarce. You'll have to look it up on the web for sample implementations.

"[Read here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/layout/package-summary#interfaces)"

Comment: Thanks. You missed a link with "Read here". Maybe it's something like https://www.raywenderlich.com/34398400-lazy-layouts-in-jetpack-compose. Is `LazyLayout` good for memory optimizations?

Comment: `LazyLayout` is DESIGNED for memory optimisation, and NO, it is nothing like the link you referred to. If I mean to say Lazy Layouts, I wouldn't enclose it in a codeblock, like I did while saying `LazyLayout`.